# Executing Python Script from NodeJS/Express instance using a relative URL

Tags: python, node.js, express

I am developing a web app that relies on NodeJS and the Express module in which I am trying to run a Python script from an express route. What I would like to do is store the Python script in `/public/scripts/test.py` and refer to it using a relative URL such as `/scripts/test.py` so that Node doesn't need to know anything about the environment in which it is running.

I've attempted to execute the Python script both by using the [python-shell module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/python-shell) and by simply using Node's built-in [ChildProcess](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). In both cases I'm running into the same issue – the path to the Python script seems to treated as being absolute and thus the script isn't executed, resulting in a file not found error.

How can I go about invoking a Python script with a relative URL? I'm rather new to web development, so I would not be surprised if I was simply misunderstanding the situation.

EDIT:
As jfreind00 pointed out, process.cwd() can be used to identify the present working directory on top of which a URL to the script can be built. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Invoking a program from node follows all the normally expected path rules.  If you precede the path with a `/`, then the system looks in the root of the current directory volume.  If you don't want node to know about your external directory structure, then set an environment variable for the location or path prefix for your python script and have the node script read that environment variable.  Either way, node has to either know about the actual path, it has to be in the node current working directory or it has to be in the path and you have to run it with something that will search the path.

Comment: Which would be an ideal solution – I guess it's not clear to me what Node considers the current directory volume. Whether I refer to the Python script as if Node's current directory were `routes/` or the root directory for the project in which `app.js` is located I still end up with a 404 error.

Comment: [`process.cwd()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) will get the current working directory.  You can just output it to the console and see what it is in your configuration.  In any given module, you also have `__filename` and `__dirname` which pertain to the particular nodejs module the code that's currently running is in.

Comment: Thanks! `process.cwd()` cleared up the situation. I was indeed making assumptions about the working directory that turned out not to be true.

Comment: I summarized the info from comments here in an answer.  Since it appears you may be new here at SO, you can indicate your answer is resolved by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer (and earn yourself some reputation points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer so you can mark this question as resolved.

Invoking a program from node follows all the normally expected path rules. If you precede the path with a `/`, then the system looks in the root of the current directory volume. If you don't want node to know about your external directory structure, then set an environment variable for the location or path prefix for your python script and have the node script read that environment variable. Either way, node has to either know about the actual path, it has to be in the node current working directory or it has to be in the path and you have to run it with something that will search the path.

If you want to see what the current working directory is in your particular configuration, then you can use:

```
console.log(process.cwd());
```

to see what the current working directory is so you can see how to base your path on that.